# How to authenticate users in Azure Active Directory with dynamic tenants inside single instance of .NET Core web application?

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-core, .net-core, active-directory

I've created the .NET Core 2.1 web application. After, this app was integrated with Azure Active Directory (`Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AzureAD`). There are a couple of tenants inside my active directory and in order to authenticate the user there is a need to provide AD tenant id, AD application client id.

Is there any way to use all tenants for authentication inside my Active Directory ?

```
public class Startup
{
     // Generated code

     public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
     {
          services.AddAuthentication(AzureADDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
                  .AddAzureAD(options => 
                              Configuration.Bind("AzureAd", options));

          services.Configure<OpenIdConnectOptions> 
                   (AzureADDefaults.OpenIdScheme, options =>
          {
               // OnTicketReceived, OnAuthenticationFailed, OnTokenValidated
          })
     }

     // Generated code
}
```

This is my `appsettings.json` file:

```
{
  "AzureAd": {
    "Instance": "https://login.microsoftonline.com",
    "Domain": "some-domain.com",
    "TenantId": "1a10b000-*******",
    "ClientId": "15a0421d-*******",
    "CallbackPath": "/signin-oidc"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For multi-tenant application the app does not know what tenant the user is from, so we can not send requests to a tenant's endpoint. To get the token from AD all the requests will go to /common endpoint (**https://login.microsoftonline.com/common**)

when Azure AD receives a request on the /common endpoint, it signs the user in and discovers which tenant the user is from. The /common endpoint doesn’t correspond to a tenant and is not an issuer, when we examine the issuer value in the metadata for /common it has a templated URL instead of an actual value:
Issuer: **https://sts.windows.net/tenantid/**

So multi-tenant application can’t validate tokens just by matching the issuer value in the metadata with the issuer value in the token. A multi-tenant application needs logic to decide which issuer values are valid and which are not based on the tenant ID portion of the issuer value.

For example, if a multi-tenant application only allows sign-in from specific tenants who have signed up for their service, then it must check either the **issuer** value or the **tenantid** claim value in the token to make sure that tenant is in their list of subscribers.

Please check the below documentation for more information about authenticating users in multi-tenant.
[Convert app to be multi-tenant](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/howto-convert-app-to-be-multi-tenant) and
[Github sample to authenticate user in multi-tenant](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-webapp-webapi-multitenant-openidconnect/blob/master/TodoList_MT/App_Start/Startup.Auth.cs)

I hope this helps.